# How to select count over 2 columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

Can someone suggest me a query to get combined count from 2 columns. My specific requirement is as following:

```
A     B       Permission
--------------------------
1     2       accept   
2     3       accept   
3     4       accept   
1     6       accept   
1     4       accept   
2     1       accept   
3     1       accept   
4     1       pending
```

I want the count of 1 whether it belong to `A` or `B` and the permission is '`accept`'. For the above example I need the output as `5`

Comment: Can you show your expected output format? Why `5`?

Comment: You listed 3 different databases. Please choose 1

Comment: Jon, DB is not an issue. It would be fine if i get solution for any specific DB . I can convert one into other later

Comment: If you have also a row with `[ 1, 1, 'accept']` data; what is `count(1)`?

Comment: That can't be the case from my requirement perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by denormalizing first the data using `UNION ALL` and then use `COUNT` to achieve the desired result:

```
WITH SampleData(A, B, Permission) AS(
    SELECT 1, 2, 'accept' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 3, 'accept' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 4, 'accept' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 6, 'accept' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 4, 'accept' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 1, 'accept' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 1, 'accept' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 1, 'pending'
)
SELECT
    t.ColValue,
    ValueCount = COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT
         Col = 'A', ColValue = A, Permission
    FROM SampleData
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
         Col = 'B', ColValue = B, Permission
    FROM SampleData
) t
WHERE Permission = 'accept'
GROUP BY t.ColValue
```

**RESULT**

```
ColValue    ValueCount
----------- -----------
1           5
2           3
3           3
4           2
6           1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE (A=1 OR B=1) AND Permission LIKE 'accept'
```

You mean this?

Comment: No, in your query i'll have to specify A=1 or B=1 whereas I need to group for all the possible values like the following:     1   =>  5, 2 => 3, 3 => 3, 4 => 2,  6 => 1 .......I hope you understand what I need

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer and changed it to work for postgre :

---

```
WITH SampleData(auid, buid, permission) AS(
 SELECT 1, 2, 'accept' UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 3, 'accept' UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 4, 'accept' UNION ALL
 SELECT 1, 6, 'accept' UNION ALL
 SELECT 1, 4, 'accept' UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 1, 'accept' UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 1, 'accept' UNION ALL
 SELECT 4, 1, 'pending')
 SELECT  t.col,   COUNT(*)as count 
 FROM (
  SELECT  auid as col, permission  FROM SampleData
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  buid as col, permission  FROM SampleData
 ) t
 WHERE permission = 'accept'
 GROUP BY t.col
```

---

**Result**

```
col          count
-----------  -----------
1            5
2            3
3            3
4            2
6            1
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said `A` or `B`, I think when you have 1 in `A` And in `B` it means 1 count; So I suggest this edited query?

```
SELECT M, COUNT(*) As C 
FROM (
    SELECT A as M, Permission
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B, Permission
    FROM yourTable 
    WHERE A <> B) Dt
WHERE Permission = 'accept'
GROUP BY M
```